# Ability to retrieve a different row based on different condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table with two columns:

| ProductId | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Global | 1 |
| P123 | 2 |
| P234 | 3 |

I have to build a query which returns the corresponding value if the Product Id exists in the table, as in if P123 --> 2.
`Select Value from Product where ProductId='P123'`

If we do not have the corresponding value for the Product Id, then return the value for the Global Product Id, as in for P456 we should return --> 1

Can you please let me know how we can perform the same in a single postgres query?

Comment: "Ability to retrieve a different row based on different condition" is a bit vague... May I suggest "Retrieving default value if filter conditions are not met" or even "Retrieving default product if id not found".

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce` on scalar subqueries.

```sql
select coalesce
(
 (select value from t where productid = 'P123'), 
 (select value from t where productid = 'Global')
) as value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter corresponding and default products and make use of ORDER and LIMIT to select the corresponding if it exists. Something like that:

```sql
SELECT 
  value 
FROM 
  product
WHERE
  ProductId='P123' OR ProductId='Global'
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN ProductId='Global' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC
LIMIT
  1
```

The `CASE` clause is needed to position product with ID 'Global' last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION

```
with data as (
  select value
  from product
  where productid = 'P123'
)
select *
from data
union all
select value
from product
where productid = 'Global'
  and not exists (select * from data);
```

The second part of the union will only be executed if the first one didn't return any results.